# Is there a way in c# to omit the response type from a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

In c# you can hide the type of the in parameter to a generic method.

Is it be possible to do the same when you have a in type and a generic method?

Code for visualization of what I am trying to achieve:

```
public class A { ... }
public class B { ... }
private Task BaseMethod<T>(T request) {
    ...
}
private Task<R> BaseMethod<T, R>(T request) {
    ...
}
public Task foo(A request) => BaseMethod(request);
// The following line works
public Task<B> bar(A request) => BaseMethod<A, B>(request);
// But I wanted something like the next line
public Task<B> bar(A request) => BaseMethod(request);
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: is there any benifit? you already codes `<B>` and `A` on the left side, so omitting it in right side only reduces one character in code length, not any designing benifit(flexisibility, maintainability, etc).

Comment: @LeiYang A and B naming is for demonstration proposes only, being possible to extrapolate in and out types would make the code more readable and less writing needed. As a disclaimer, please never name your classes A and B in production ready code.

Comment: There is something alike https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki#basics - maybe it satisfies your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not currently a thing that is supported in the language.